# Are "filename expansion" and "pathname expansion" the same thing in Bash?

Tags: bash

Bash Reference Manual sometimes mentions "filename expansion" and sometimes but less often "pathname expansion".

I have been thinking they are the same concept. But the same manual mentions the two without defining the second, which makes me uncertain. So are they the same or different?

Comment: With all your questions about the `bash` man page I have to wonder if you've ever gotten as far as `LESS=+/^AUTHORS man bash`.  :D

Comment: I think it's great, by the way.  I intend to read the entire bash man page myself someday , and I expect your questions (and the answers to them) will be a great help to me when I do.

Comment: Thanks. Never expect the authors will read my questions, because I have many. Plus whoever wrote it might not be those who can explain it well.  I must say the Bash Reference Manual is one of the least organized manual I have read.

Comment: See the first bug: `LESS=+/^BUGS man bash`

Comment: Try the bash info pages instead.  but use `pinfo` rather than `info`.  `pinfo` works llke a text-mode web browser such as `lynx` or `links`.  `info` itself is probably only comprehensible/usable by long-term `emacs` addicts.  You may need to install the `bash-doc` package if your distro doesn't include the full .info documentation with the `bash` package itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

- Visit [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) in which you'll find section **Pathname Expansion.**
- Visit [**Filename Expansion**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) from Bash Reference Manual.

And recognize that both are talking about same-thing. (also known as *globbing*)